# How can I simulate latency in Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, simulation, latency

Currently, I'm testing my Node.js, Socket.io server on `localhost` and on devices connected to my router.

For testing purposes, I would like to simulate a delay in sending messages, so I know what it'll be like for users around the world.

Is there any effective way of doing this?

Comment: Override `socket.emit()` and delay every send by a certain number of seconds by sending it on a `setTimeout()` delay.

Comment: @jfriend00, yes! Please answer! :)

Answer (score 10):

If it's the messages you send from the server that you want to delay, you can override the `.emit()` method on each new connection with one that adds a short delay.  Here's one way of doing that on the server:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("socket connected: ", socket.id);
    
    // override the .emit() method
    const emitFn = socket.emit
    socket.emit = (...args) => setTimeout(() => {
        emitFn.apply(socket, args)
    }, 1000) 


    // rest of your connection handler here
 });
```

Note, there is one caveat with this.  If you pass an object or an array as the data for `socket.emit()`, you will see that this code does not make a copy of that data so the data will not be actually used until the data is sent (1 second from now).  So, if the code doing the sending actually modifies that data before it is sent one second from now, that would likely create a problem.  This could be fixed by making a copy of the incoming data, but I did not add that complexity here as it would not always be needed since it depends upon how the caller's code works.

Answer (score 2):

An old but still popular question.  :)

You can use either "iptables" or "tc" to simulate delays/dropped-packets.  See the man page for "iptables" and look for 'statistic'.  I suggest you make sure to specify the port or your ssh session will get affected.

Here are some good examples for "tc":
http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem

Comment: A quick google brings up "TMnetSim Network Simulator"